# Remove scrolls on ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services

i need to remove both scrolls from a .rdl report, when i upload it to the reporting services report server it shows both scrolls.

Ty in advance

Comment: What browser are you using to view the reports?

Comment: im using explorer, but i tested in firefox too and its the same

Answer (score 0):

By default the SSRS reports loads into a frame when gets accessed by the report server.

So, there is nothing much to do with it unless you are integrating the report in some web front thing,Like ASP.NET website.